# Input in a 2-D array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was trying to solve a question on 2-D matrix, but unfortunately the matrix input was giving an error. This is the code:

```
int arr[4][4];
int r, c;
scanf("%d", &r);
scanf("%d", &c);
int i, j;
fflush(stdin);
for(i = 0; i < r; i++)
    for(j = 0; j < c; j++)
        scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
```

When I run this, it takes extra input.
For example: if `r = 2` and `c = 2`> then it takes 6 input and then hangs. What to do?

Comment: What does your code do after the loops? It sounds like the input is working correctly.

Comment: I concur. This code only would work as expected (as long as `r` and `c`  are not more than 4).

Comment: when `r=2 and c=2`, it should only take 4 numbers. I don't see any problem with the code segment you posted. Can you post the complete code?

Comment: if i take r=2 and c=2 then it asks for 6 inputs and then when i enter them, the output screen closes automatically.

Comment: It is only working for r=1 and c=1 else its not working.:(

Comment: you read 6 numbers in total as per your code. What's your expected output and can you please post the complete code?

Comment: Why are you fflushing stdin ?

Comment: and also start avoiding scanf() to probe user input. use fgets() and then use atoi(). scanf() can eat your data silently

Answer (score 1):

If r=2 and c=2, it executes the first 2 scanf and then the 2x2 scanf of your 2D loop.

This makes 2 + 2x2 = 6.

After the last scanf, if your program is finished, it simply closes, that's normal.

Comment: Am I missing something in the question ?

Answer (score 1):

I have copied your code and tried executing it and I observed that it is showing the behaviour told by you if we are taking **r** and **c** greater than their limits. So use proper limits.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with your code is that you've allocated a fixed amount of space for your array but allowed the user to provide an arbitrary number of inputs by making the bounds of your loop the user-provided `r` and `c`variables. Thus if the user provides `r=6` and `c=6`, at some point your loop will attempt to dereference `arr[5][5]`, which is invalid since you've defined `int arr[4][4];`. If you want to allow the user to create as many rows and columns as they want, you should initialize `arr` with the user-provided input, like this:

```
int r,c;
scanf("%d",&r);
scanf("%d",&c);
int arr[r][c];
```

Comment: if he's not using c99 does variable length arrays for stack work?

Comment: @aftnix, I don't understand what you mean by "variable length arrays for stack." If he's not using C99, he can't use variable-length arrays, because they were a feature introduced in C99. The workaround is to use `malloc` to manually create the array, as explained [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-cwhy-variable-length-arrays/184401444?pgno=1).

Comment: i was just pointing it out that if he's not using c99 then variable length array will not work.

Answer (score -1):

In your code you have simply run a loop and how much value will be scan depend on the how many loops has executed. 
Suppose you take r=1,c=1. 
In this condition for every "r" value c will executed single time.
So When your value will be larger than the array size that time it will give you abnormal behavior.

if you will firstly input the value of "c", and "r"after that it will behave normally.

```
int r, c;
scanf("%d", &r);
scanf("%d", &c);
int arr[r][c];
```

Comment: I don't see how this is supposed to be an answer to the original question.

Comment: Removing downvote... you probably wanted to show how a custom sized array can be allocated. While it is not an actual answer, it contains valuable information.

Comment: Yes i only showing that how can i customize array and also give the proper logic why questioner's answer giving undefined behavior.I am only try to remove his problem and want to resolve it in his way.